# How to access the filtered list of related objects when using FilteredRelation?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a list of Funds that I have to query by their related model Commitment (as in "return the funds in which associated commitments fill this criteria).

I need to annotate each fund with an aggregation over the filtered commitments, as well as access each item in the filtered relation.

I'm trying to use `FilteredRelation`:

```
funds = Fund.objects.annotate(
    f_commitments=FilteredRelation(
        "commitments",
        condition=Q(pk="c40ae23d-50ee-47c5-9397-c1670098ecd9")
    )
)
```

I'm trying a basic query just to test the filter. The query runs, but the funds it returns don't have a `f_commitments` attribute as it usually does with annotations:

```
AttributeError: 'Fund' object has no attribute 'f_commitments'
```

Is there something wrong with the query or FilteredRelation don't support accessing the filtered items directly?

Comment: Is this exactly how your usage is like? I've seen `AttributeError` raised when I annotate but forget to update the fund variable to include the new annotation (queryset methods do not modify the existing queryset but creates a new one)

Comment: @Ladmerc yes, I'd do `funds[0].f_commitments`. I think I might be able to get it working using prefetch, if I do i'll add an answer